# How to include a stored procedure in F#

Tags: sql-server, f#

In the following code, I would like to insert or update rows in an SQL table through F#.
It takes a matrix of tuple representing users and an associated scores (usrID,score) which are the results of some F# calculations.
Now I want to update a SQL table called UserScoresTable.
The code I wrote is working but is very slow.

```ml
let cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("Database").ConnectionString)
cnn.Open()

// Definition d'une fonction qui execute une demande sous MySQL
let execNonQuery s =
    let comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(s, cnn, CommandTimeout = 10)
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore

// Definition d'une fonction qui utilise les éléments d'une matrice pour updater une table dans MySQL
let updateMySQLTable (m : Matrix<float * float>) =
    for j in 0 .. (snd m.Dimensions) - 1 do
        for i in 1 .. (fst m.Dimensions) - 1 do
        // first check if the user and score and date do not exist
            sprintf "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductScores WHERE UserID = %f AND ProductID = %f) INSERT INTO ProductScores (UserID, Score, Date) VALUES (%f, %f,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"  (fst m.[i, j]) (snd m.[i, j])
            |>  execNonQuery
       // otherwise update the row
            sprintf "UPDATE ProductScores SET Score = %f, Date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE UserID = %f " (snd m.[i, j]) (fst m.[i, j])
            |>  execNonQuery
```

I would like to avoid the two execNonQuery requests in the code by using a stored procedure such as

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE updateScoreByUsers 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserID int, 
    @Score  float

AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM ProductScores WHERE UserID = @UserID ) 
        INSERT INTO 
        ProductScores (UserID, Score, Date) VALUES (@UserID,@Score,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ELSE

    UPDATE ProductScores 
        SET Score = @Score, Date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        WHERE UserID = @UserID 
END
GO
```

But I don't know how to call a SQL stored procedure in F#.
How can I call it with F#?
DO you see any other way of improvements?

Comment: Your management of the ADO.NET objects seems a bit fragile.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL or MySQL?

Comment: Sorry I am using MS SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `SqlCommand.CommandText` to the name of the stored procedure and set `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`. For example

```
use cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", con)
cmd.CommandType <- CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you're on 2008 you may want to look into the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

To significantly improve performance you need to avoid making a database call for each item. Perhaps use `SqlBulkCopy` to load all the data to the server at once (use a temp table or designated staging table), then use set-based operations (`UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`MERGE`) to merge with your target table.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, just doing the two statements in a single SQL command isn't going to improve the performance much. To make it really efficient, you'll need to transfer the data from `Matrix` to the database and then update the table. To copy the data, you could use `SqlBulkCopy` (see [MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)), which lets you upload a large amount of data efficiently. You can use this to insert data in a new table and then run a single SQL command to update the data in the actual table.

---

Aside - Daniel's answer is the most direct way to call a stored proecdure from F#. If you want to make it a bit nicer, you can also use the dynamic operator, which let's you write something like this:

```
db?MyStoredProcedure(userId, scores)
```

... instead of creating and executing `SqlCommand` by hand. This can be done using a `DynamicDatabase` type that is implemented in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304373.aspx).

Comment: Thank you thomas and Daniel, based on your recommandation I am going to use SQLBulkCopy. I am sure you already know this but just in case, one of my friend just told me that the new F# update, which should come soon, will include some convient functions to communicate with SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033(v=vs.110).aspx