# Using SqlBulkCopy with F# to export matrix in SQL

Tags: sql, f#, matrix, sqlbulkcopy

I want to transfer a large amount of data from F# to an SQL table. Basically my F# code creates a matrix of three columns (`UserID, ProductID and price`) and N lines. I would like to "copy/pate it" into a database
I tried several options but at the end, the transfer of data from F# is really slow (around one hour for 10000 lines).

Thanks to answers of a previous question [How to include a stored procedure in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899678/how-to-include-a-stored-procedure-in-f/8899791#8899791), an interesting way to resolve this problem is to use `SqlBulkCopy`.

`SqlBulkCopy` requires a database type for its `WritetoServer` method but I didn't find any existing code or simple way to convert a matrix into a database.
Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: What is the type of your "matrix"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started (and reference the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for more information about `SqlBulkCopy`):

```ml
//you must reference System.Data and System.Xml
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

let bulkLoadUserPurchases (conn:SqlConnection) (userPurchases: list<int * int * float>) =
    use sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null, BatchSize=500, BulkCopyTimeout=1200, DestinationTableName="YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE")
    sbc.WriteToServer(
        let dt = new DataTable()
        ["UserID", typeof<int>
         "ProductID", typeof<int>
         "Price", typeof<float>]
        |> List.iter (dt.Columns.Add>>ignore)

        for userPurchase in userPurchases do
            let userId, productId, price = userPurchase
            let dr = dt.NewRow()
            dr.["UserID"] <- userId
            dr.["ProductID"] <- productId
            dr.["Price"] <- price
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dt)
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen, it is perfectly doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with third party libraries, [fastmember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember/ObjectReader.cs) can be **really** useful here.

```ml
module DB =
    open System.Data
    open System.Data.SqlClient
    open FastMember

    // val bulk : conn:SqlConnection -> table:string -> columns:seq<string*string> -> items:seq<a'>
    let bulk conn table columns items =        
        use bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection = conn)
        bcp.EnableStreaming <- true
        bcp.DestinationTableName <- table
        for n,v in columns do   
            bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(sourceColumn = n, destinationColumn = v))               
            |> ignore
        bcp.WriteToServer(items |> ObjectReader.Create)
```

This leaves you with a generic method that you can just funnel any `seq<a'>` into. Along with some config parameters, which you can of course configure to your needs.