# Haskell HDBC Elegance in F#?

Tags: ado.net, f#, haskell, hdbc

I'm struck by Haskell's terseness and elegance. But I work in a .Net house, so I use F# when I can get away with it--I may be the only one of hundreds across the country who uses it.

Does ADO.NET or F# offer something as terse and elegant as HDBC's `executeMany`? I'm making my way through [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/). In [chapter 21](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html) it offers this example:

```hs
ghci> conn <- connectSqlite3 "test1.db"
ghci> stmt <- prepare conn "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)"
ghci> executeMany stmt [[toSql 5, toSql "five's nice"], [toSql 6, SqlNull]]
ghci> commit conn
ghci> disconnect conn
```

I'd like to get this elegance and terseness in my F#. I've seen a lot of hype around using parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks. I'm not using them in this case for three reasons:

1. I find parameterized queries in .Net ugly and burdensome.
2. My data comes from the corporate office, so it's (mostly) clean.
3. My table has 34 columns. I despise the idea of parameterizing a query with 34 columns.

Here's my F# code:

```ml
module Data

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.OleDb
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

type Period = Prior | Current

let Import period records db =
    use conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + db + ";Persist Security Info=False;")

    let execNonQuery s =
        let comm = new OleDbCommand(s, conn) in
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore

    let enquote = sprintf "\"%s\""
    let escapeQuotes s = Regex.Replace(s, "\"", "\"\"")
    let join (ss:string[]) = String.Join(",", ss)

    let table = match period with
                | Prior   -> "tblPrior"
                | Current -> "tblCurrent"
    let statements =
        [| for r in records do
               let vs = r |> Array.map (escapeQuotes >> enquote) |> join
               let vs' = vs + sprintf ",\"14\",#%s#" (DateTime.Now.ToString "yyyy-MM-dd") in
               yield sprintf "INSERT INTO %s ( [Field01], [Field02], [Field03] [Field04], [Field05], [Field06], [Field07], [Field08], [Field09], [Field10], [Field11], [Field12], [Field13], [Field14], [Field15], [Field16], [Field17], [Field18], [Field19], [Field20], [Field21], [Field22], [Field23], [Field24], [Field25], [Field26], [Field27], [Field28], [Field29], [Field30], [Field31], [Field32], [Field33], [Field34] ) VALUES (%s)" table vs' |] in

    do conn.Open()
    execNonQuery (sprintf "DELETE FROM %s" table)
    statements |> Array.iter execNonQuery
```

I've renamed the fields of the table(s) for security reasons.

Because all the fields on the table are text, I can easily Array.map them to escape and quote the values.

At between 9,000 and 10,000 records per day to import to each of the two tables, I want to do this as efficiently as possible. Hence my interest in the `executeMany` of Haskell. Too, though, I like the idea behind parameterized queries, and I like the way Hasekll has implemented them. Is there something equivalent in terseness and elegance in F#?

Comment: I don't know if it is as elegant as Hasekll  but the type provider in F# 3.0 is far more elegant than building insert statements.

Comment: "*I may be the only one of hundreds across the country who uses it.*" Uh, no.

Comment: @ildjarn Methinks you misunderstood to what he was referring.  I'm pretty sure the "hundreds" are the people in his company.

Comment: That's right, I meant of the hundreds in my company. :)

Comment: Ah, I did indeed misunderstand, apologies. :-]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with @JonnyBoats comment that generally using an F# SQL type provider like [SqlDataConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx) (LINQ-to-SQL) or [SqlEntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361035.aspx) (Entity Framework) would be far more elegant than any kind of solution involving building insert statement strings by hand.

But, there is one important qualifier to your question: "At between 9,000 and 10,000 records per day to import to each of the two tables, I want to do this as efficiently as possible." In a scenario like this, you'll want to use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for efficient bulk inserts (it leverages native database driver features for much faster inserts than you are likely getting with HDBC's `executeMany`).

Here's a small example that should help you getting started using `SqlBulkCopy` with F#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8942056/236255. Note that you'll be working with a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to stage the data which though old and somewhat awkward to use from F#, is still superior to building insert statement strings in my opinion.

**Update in response to comment**

Here's a generalized approach to using `SqlBulkCopy` which is improved for your scenario (we pass in a column specification separately from the row data, and both are dynamic):

```ml
//you must reference System.Data and System.Xml
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

let bulkLoad (conn:SqlConnection) tableName (columns:list<string * Type>) (rows: list<list<obj>>) =
    use sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null, BatchSize=500, BulkCopyTimeout=1200, DestinationTableName=tableName)
    sbc.WriteToServer(
        let dt = new DataTable()
        columns
        |> List.iter (dt.Columns.Add>>ignore)

        for row in rows do
            let dr = dt.NewRow()
            row |> Seq.iteri(fun i value -> dr.[i] <- value)
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        dt)

//example usage:

//note: since you know all your columns are of type string, you could define columns like
//let columns = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3"] |> List.map (fun name -> name, typeof<String>)
let columns = [
    "Field1", typeof<String>
    "Field2", typeof<String>
    "Field3", typeof<String>
]

let rows = [
    ["a"; "b"; "c"]
    ["d"; "e"; "f"]
    ["g"; "h"; "i"]
    ["j"; "k"; "l"]
    ["m"; "n"; "o"]
]

//a little funkiness to transform our list<list<string>> to list<list<obj>>, 
//probably not needed in practice because you won't be constructing your lists literally
let rows = rows |> List.map (fun row -> row |> List.map (fun value -> value :> obj))

bulkLoad conn "tblPrior" columns rows
```

You could get even fancier / more terse using an approach involving reflection. e.g. create a type like

```ml
type RowData = { Field1:string; Field2:string; Field3:string }
```

and make a `bulkLoad` with a signature that takes a `list<'a>` argument such that it reflects over the property names and types of `typeof<'a>` to build the `DataTable` `Columns`, and similarly uses reflection to iterate over all the properties of a row instance to create and add a new row to the `DataTable`. In fact, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253725/236255) shows how to make a generic `ToDataTable` method that does it (in C#).

Comment: Thanks for telling me about SqlBulkCopy, and for the pointer to your example. I wonder, though, if F# can't do better. What kills me the most about your example is that it requires referencing the column names twice. At 34 columns, that's 68 points of duplication (my own, ad hoc, statistic--not to be interpreted rigorously). After typing all that out, I'd feel the need to shower, and would hate looking at my work.

Comment: @JeffManer yeah, I hear ya. F# the language can certainly be as expressive as your Haskell here, but the APIs just aren't there yet (as far as I know). However, I've updated may answer with a `SqlBulkCopy` approach generalized and improved for your scenario (column names and types only need to be specified once).

Comment: @StephenSwenson, thank you so much! Unfortunately, `SqlBulkCopy` can only be used to write to SQL Server tables. In this instance, I'm writing to Access tables. But I've got another project in which I write to SQL Server tables. I'll try using your new and improved example there! :)